# Workgroups doesn't load the files from last session on startup

Tags: workgroups

I needed emacs to startup and show me all the files I worked on last time (whom I didn't close explicitly) before `M-x kill-emacs`. I installed Workgroups for it and my prefix is `C-c w`. I split the window, ran a few files and I saved a workgroup. After restarting, it showed me all the files I closed last time (first usage). 
After I worked on some other files, I closed emacs. But the next time I tried to start it, it shows me the files from the first session. My last session wasn't saved and instead my first session files are being shown.

I want to automatically load the files I ran the last time before closing to be arranged just the way it was. 
How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you show me your configure?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `kill-emacs`, it will not save the session on exit. You must call `save-buffers-kill-terminal` or the default exit `C-x C-c`. So either call `save-buffers-kill-emacs` or `save-buffers-kill-terminal`, or add `wg-save-session-on-emacs-exit` to `kill-emacs-hook`.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to put `(workgroups-mode 1)` at the bottom of your .emacs. This line code will restore workspaces session.

Comment: No, I have this enabled. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should do an minimal emacs init content debug?